All Airflow jobs failing locally ERROR:"Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT"
I am having an issue where no matter what Airflow job I run, it fails with the error:
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: local_to_s3_dag.local_to_s3_task manual__2024-04-03T22:26:53.513679+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: local_to_s3_dag.local_to_s3_task manual__2024-04-03T22:26:53.513679+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {taskinstance.py:1308} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {taskinstance.py:1327} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): local_to_s3_task> on 2024-04-03 22:26:53.513679+00:00
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 9751 to run task
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'local_to_s3_dag', 'local_to_s3_task', 'manual__2024-04-03T22:26:53.513679+00:00', '--job-id', '3', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/local_to_s3_dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/var/folders/z7/50r70c7n2klfyy8qsv4fs97c0000gn/T/tmpbtxeqy6d']
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 3: Subtask local_to_s3_task
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: local_to_s3_dag.local_to_s3_task manual__2024-04-03T22:26:53.513679+00:00 [running]> on host nicholass-macbook-pro-2.local
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {taskinstance.py:1545} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='NAME' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='local_to_s3_dag' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='local_to_s3_task' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2024-04-03T22:26:53.513679+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2024-04-03T22:26:53.513679+00:00'
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - Got all filenames
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT
[2024-04-03, 15:26:57 PDT] {taskinstance.py:2653} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

At first I thought it was specific to the work that I was doing because I read that the error code means something is wrong with the task but now even when I test with a simple task like moving data from my local machine to an S3 bucket, the job will fail. Here is the dag I have been testing with below:
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from pytz import timezone
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import boto3
# from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.transfers.local_to_s3 import LocalToS3Operator

def upload_file_to_s3(filename, bucket_name, s3_key):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_file(filename, bucket_name, s3_key)
    print(f"File {filename} uploaded to S3 bucket {bucket_name} with key {s3_key}")

def upload_file_to_s3_task(**kwargs):
    filename = kwargs.get('filename')
    bucket_name = kwargs.get('bucket_name')
    s3_key = kwargs.get('s3_key')
    print('Got all filenames')
    upload_file_to_s3(filename, bucket_name, s3_key)

pst = timezone('US/Pacific')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Name',
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 1, 29, 8, 53, tzinfo=pst),
    'end_date': datetime(2025, 1, 31, 8, 54, tzinfo=pst)
}

with DAG(dag_id="local_to_s3_dag",
         default_args=default_args,
         description="Takes local CSV and moves to S3 bucket",
         schedule="@weekly") as dag:
             
    upload_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='local_to_s3_task',
    python_callable=upload_file_to_s3_task,
    op_kwargs={
        'filename': '/Users/myuser/Desktop/filepath', 
        'bucket_name': 'bucket',
        's3_key': 'data.csv'  
    }
    )


    upload_task

I have been trouble shooting for hours and have no idea what the issue is, can anyone help me?
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling airflow, updating all relevant libaries, and using different DAGS to see if any of them worked.

It is a difficult to say without additional logs to figure out in which place SIGABRT happen. Try to enable faulthandler into the scheduler and worker, it could be done by set any value into environment variable PYTHONFAULTHANDLER. Run your DAG again and update your question with additional information.
